# Can Drupal be used with PostGIS, allowing for spatial queries?

Tags: drupal, postgis

Can Drupal be used with PostGIS, allowing for spatial queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it definitely can.

For example, you could use the [Geo module](http://drupal.org/project/geo) which supports both PostGIS and MySQL spatial, it even integrates nicely with CCK and Views.

Personally I wrote my own module instead because I needed different widgets and some very specific thing with multypolygons, but the geo module works quite well.

Comment: The OpenLayers module integrates nicely with the above to provide a UI for structuring some of these queries via Views (http://drupal.org/project/openlayers)